# Display list of SSRS reports in a dropdown list, and allow users to select which report to display

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

Our company has about 10 different SSRS reports. We would like to allow users to navigate from one report to another simply by selecting the report from a dropdown list. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Reports should be stored in the Catalog table in the SSRS database, you should be able to create a report based off the contents of the Catalog table...

Comment: This is the correct answer. I did this before using a "Report Index" that would generate off of the catalog views. It's pretty trivial to do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You would need to write your own custom web app to interact with each SSRS instance.

You would do all of this using the .NET library around SSRS, it includes methods and such for interacting with reports in SSRS. A small/basic example: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Local-SSRS-Report-in-ASPNet-Tutorial-with-example.aspx